# How to handle null values in date field in sql pgadmin

Tags: sql, casting, pgadmin, isnull, date-difference

I need to find difference between two dates to calculate "total storage days" in pgadmin

date1-date2=total storage days

The date values is having null values, if i use `isnull(date1,0)`

> ERROR:  function isnull(date, unknown) does not exist
>  HINT:  No
> function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
> add explicit type casts.

If i use isnull(cast(date2 as integer),0)
ERROR:  cannot cast type date to integer

Please help me to calculate difference of 2 dates to find total storage date, if date field having null value also need to calculate total storage date

Comment: I think you need to look into the datediff() function instead of trying to set the nulls to an integer - https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

Comment: @DaveWuzHere, OP seems to be using Postgresql (pdadmin), not SQL Server. No need to link to w3f**ls.

Answer (score 0):

***It calculate difference between date1 and date2 if not null both else 0***

```
Select 
Case When date1 is not null And date2 is not null
Then DATEDIFF(day,date1,date2) Else 0 End total From TableName
```

Comment: In Pgadmin, For DATEDIFF(day,date1,date2) below error displays                                    
               ERROR:  column "day" does not exist

Comment: Replace EXTRACT(DAY FROM (endDate - startDate) instead of DATEDIFF